# HTML response on local server is gibberish

Tags: c#, http, tcplistener

Problem Solved by using http instead of https.Thanks Kalten

This is my first HTTP server made by using .Net TcpListener.My code looks like this :

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 44394);
            tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] requestBytes = new byte[100000];

                    int readBytes = stream.Read(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

                    var requestResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBytes,0,readBytes);
                    Console.WriteLine(requestResult);

                    Console.WriteLine(new string('>',50)); //for splitting responses

                }

            }
```

Client used to send request Chrome with url : https://localhost:44394/

The string it returns looks like this :

�u$�15�q��νѴ��Q�~YWzw4� ��}� u�8BЎeJ��43x���;��?��d@���~ "ZZ�+�/�,�0̨̩�� � � / 5 
 ���            localhost   �

��       #     h2http/1.1
      3 + )��     �d{�p��{���|�Pu����;^ܑ��/ -  + 
zz   ::    �

Things I've tried:
1.Decode the byte array manually with online byte to utf-8 converter(I get error that these bytes are not valid to transcribe to utf-8)
2.Tried to decompress it using Gzip (It returns error that the content is not gzip)

Comment: What did the client sent?

Comment: Servers don't "return" requests out of thin air.  Some client must send a request, which you receive and display.  Explain precisely what client you used, and exactly how you used it.

Comment: I used chrome and just entered the url : https://localhost:44394/

Comment: You are trying to call your server with httpS protocol. It require ssl/tls encryption and associated certificate. Try to call with http protocol or use [sslstream](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream)